# How am I building this date format wrong?

Tags: ios

I've almost got this working, and obviously I've gotten parts of it working since the time is ALMOST correct (it's one hour short of what it should be)

```
InputDate: Sat Oct 27 22:08:36 PDT 2012
Resulting Date:  2012-01-01 05:08:36 +0000
(Or:  Saturday, December 31, 2011 9:21 PM)
```

Here is the code I'm using to encapsulate the string data into an NSDate:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz YYYY"];
NSDate *buildDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:buildDateString];
```

To rephrase a bit:  input date is the date that's getting put INTO the date formatter.  The resulting date is simply an NSLog of the NSDate generated by the date formatter.

I'm trying to take an externally generated date (generated by the build phase, as I want the build timestamp to be available in-app) and transform that string into an NSDate, which I can then output readily using the existing iOS controls.

Comment: This is kind of confusing. The sample date is 10/27/2012, resulting dat is 1/1/2012, and then 12/31? Sample date is 10:08, resulting date is 5:08 (you say it's one hour off?) Also, what does your buildDateString look like?

Comment: You most likely want yyyy for the year, not YYYY. And yes, show us buildDateString.

Comment: I've clarified my post a little -- buildDateString is the actual date, relabled inputdate, that I gave.  The resulting date is the result of my NSLog outputs, and I included the slightly cleaned up version that I'm going to output at the end of this process.

Comment: I don't understand HOW the year part can make the day and month part wrong...  if you make that an answer, I'll accept it.  I thought I tried that at some point, but clearly I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rmaddy added the correct answer as a comment, but never made it an actual answer so that I could accept it.  The key was using 'yyyy' instead of 'YYYY'

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `+0000` for `zzz`.

```
z~zzz:  (Specific GMT Timezone Abbreviation) 
zzzz:   (Specific GMT Timezone Name) 
Z:  +0000 (RFC 822 Timezone)
```

Please refer [this link](http://tahabebek.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/format-string-for-the-iphone-nsdateformatter/) for detailed format for string in dateformatter. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hrm...  I think you misunderstood my (perhaps not as clear as it should have been) question; my issue is with using the dateformatter to take IN a date, not output it.